# Android 10+ anti SMS spam filter

Tags: android, filter, sms, spam

Android 10+ has anti SMS spam function in default SMS application.

Is possible to write you own filter and add it as extension to the application?
Something similarly to iOS solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is a feature of the specific application.

There is no such API or functionality supported by Android out of the box.